# Vscode scroll through current IntelliSense using keyboard shortcut

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

**Is there a keyboard shortcut to scroll through current Vscode Intellisense details?**

[image: Vscode intellisense screenshot]

I can use the arrows for the overloads showing as  `1/2`, but I am talking about the text itself.

**It sucks having to walk to the mouse many times only for this while coding**

Comment: I submitted the relevant function development request in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/166883) for you, but unfortunately there was no response.